# Исправление html, следуя w3.validator

Tags: seo, валидация, html-validation

Прогоняю страницы сайта через validator.w3.org. Подозреваю, что другие HTML-валидаторы будут также ругаться...

Вылезает ошибка та же по сути, но на разных элементах.

### Вариант 1

> Error: Attribute **secondaryImage** not allowed on element **img** at this
>   point.

Ошибка указывает на вот этот тэг (сокращен для простоты):

```
<img src="[путь-к-главной-картинке]" secondaryImage="[путь-ко-второй-картинке]">
```

Вторая картинка показывается при наведении мышкой на src.
*Суть:* `secondaryImage` мне необходим для корректной работы сайта.

### Вариант 2

> Error: Attributes **fieldtype** and **optional** are not allowed on element **input** at this point.

Ошибка указывает на вот этот тэг (сокращен для простоты):

```
<input type="TEXT" name="searchStr" FIELDTYPE="TEXT" OPTIONAL="YES">
```

Перед отправкой формы запускается библиотека, которая проверяет заполнение полей, используя эти дополнительные аттрибуты.
*Суть:* аттрибуты необходимы для корректной работы библиотеки валидации.

.

Я знаю как решить все эти проблемы. Просто это на данном этапе развития сайта это большой объем работы.
.

### Итак, основной вопрос:

**насколько серьезна эта ошибка валидатора**?

Связывался ли кто-то с такой проблемой, что seo-шники потом требовали устранять это под страхом смерти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. С точки зрения валидатора:
   Кастомные атрибуты надо начинать с префикса `data` и писать маленькими буквами.
2. С точки зрения браузеров:
   Съедят все.
3. С точки зрения SEO:
   Понятия не имею. Влияние кажется мне маловероятным.

---

```
<img src="[путь-к-главной-картинке]" data-secondary-image="[путь-ко-второй-картинке]">
<input type="text" name="searchStr" data-field-type="TEXT" data-optional="YES">
```

Comment: Интересно. насчет `data` - видел в bootstrap и других, но не думал, что это стандарт. Попробую изменить на secondary image, прогоню через валидатор. Отпишу здесь.

Comment: @cyadvert, это не только стандарт именования, это ещё и особая фича: http://jsfiddle.net/jx3kd5zz/, вот информация по [поддержке браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) - частичная - это работать как с атрибутами - это везде работает. А полная - это именно через dataset, как в моём примере.

Answer (score 2):

Опасность кастомных атрибутов не в том, что они что-то ломают сейчас, а в том, что они потенциально могут что-нибудь сломать в будущем. Вот выйдет новая версия браузера, которая особым образом обрабатывает атрибут OPTIONAL - и во что сайты превратятся?)

А для data-атрибутов гарантируется, что браузер никогда не будет их как-то обрабатывать, кроме занесения в dataset.